# Angular drag and drop - hiding droppables causes the index to malfunction

Tags: html, angular, typescript, drag-and-drop, draggable

I have a 2-dimensional dashboard of widgets on a 3x3 grid. I allow customization of the dashboard. The customization works in such fashion, that the widgets that are removed from the dashboard are marked as hidden and filtered out.

When I hide some of the widgets, the dashboard starts malfunctioning through. It seems as if the index of the total items is taken instead of the visible items (meaning if I remove 2 widgets, I have to drop 2 spaces behind for the widget to land on the correct place).

I've tried passing the visibleItems array instead of the total items BehaviorSubject in the entered method. I've also tried to enable OnPush change detection to trigger the index to update. Neither worked. What am I doing wrong?

```
<div class="dashboard-container" [class.opened]="dashboardWidgetService.isEditMode$ | async">
  <div *ngIf="dashboardWidgetService.isEditMode$ | async" class="dashboard-sidebar">
    <div *ngFor="let widget of dashboardWidgetService.hiddenItems$ | async; let i = index" class="widget-preview">
      <mat-icon>{{ widget.icon }}</mat-icon>
      <h3>{{ widget.title | translate }}</h3>
      <button color="accent" mat-icon-button (click)="dashboardWidgetService.showWidget(widget.id)">
        <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </div>

    <p *ngIf="(dashboardWidgetService.hiddenItems$ | async).length === 0" class="empty-text">
      {{ 'ProjectAllocation_Text_WidgetsEmpty' | translate }}
    </p>

    <div class="save-button-container">
      <button color="primary" mat-flat-button (click)="dashboardWidgetService.isEditMode$.next(false)">
        {{ 'Global_Button_End' | translate }}
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <mat-grid-list cols="12" rowHeight="130px" gutterSize="20px">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let widget of visibleItems; let i = index">
      <mat-grid-tile *ngIf="widget.disableDrag" [colspan]="widget.cols" [rowspan]="widget.rows">
        <div class="widget-wrapper">
          <div [ngTemplateOutlet]="widgets" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ widget: widget.id }"></div>
        </div>
      </mat-grid-tile>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let widget of visibleItems; let i = index">
      <mat-grid-tile *ngIf="!widget.disableDrag" [colspan]="widget.cols" [rowspan]="widget.rows">
        <cdk-drop-list [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="drops" [cdkDropListData]="i">
          <div
            class="widget-wrapper"
            cdkDrag
            (cdkDragEntered)="entered($event)"
            [cdkDragData]="i"
            [cdkDragDisabled]="dashboardWidgetService.isEditMode$ | async"
          >
            <div [ngTemplateOutlet]="widgets" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ widget: widget.id }"></div>
          </div>
        </cdk-drop-list>
      </mat-grid-tile>
    </ng-container>
    <mat-grid-tile *ngIf="!(dashboardWidgetService.isEditMode$ | async)" [colspan]="12">
      <button mat-flat-button (click)="dashboardWidgetService.isEditMode$.next(true)" color="primary">
        {{ 'Global_Button_Edit' | translate }}
      </button>
    </mat-grid-tile>
  </mat-grid-list>
</div>



  public entered($event: CdkDragEnter): void {
    moveItemInArray(this.dashboardWidgetService.items$.value, $event.item.data, $event.container.data);
    this.dashboardWidgetService.items$.next(this.dashboardWidgetService.items$.value);
  }
```